# less specific style getting applied by browser

Tags: css, css-specificity

```
<body>
    <section id="section">
        <nav class="class1 class2 class3">
            <ul class="class4 class5" id="ul">
                <li><a></a></li>
                <li><a></a></li>
                <li><a></a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </section>
</body>
```

Selector 1:

```
.class2 .class5 > li > a {
    color: #777777;
}
```

vs

Selector 2:

```
body #section .class1.class3 #ul {
    color: #fff;
}
```

Clearly selector 2 has higher specificity but still browser applies the styles as selector 1.

Comment: selector2 won't match anything as it has two id selectors and an element should only have one id. I think you meant to use descendent css selectors like in selector1.

Answer (score 0):

In the first selector, you're applying the styles to the anchor tags, in the second you're applying the styles to the unordered list.

The white color is applied to the list, and anything inside that list **that does not have its own color applied** will be colored white.

In this case, the gray color from the first selector is displayed because it is directly applied to the anchor elements whereas the gray color from the second selector is only implicitly applied to the anchors, allowing the gray color to override it.